# Best Practice to avoid Popup Block in Browser involving Ajax event

Tags: javascript, ajax, popup

I know this might sound similar to a few questions on SO already, but they somehow don't convince me with any best practice.

Now I know, its a pretty straightforward advice while using AJAX, never (ever) go for Synchronized XHR. But what if that XHR is part of some validation criteria which if succeeds has to open some popups. The moment the asynch XHR is invoked, the User Event has ended. The Popups that were intended to open in the callback will never happen if the browser is doing its job well.

What should be nice workaround that might settle for best practice in such scenario.

One clean solution that I've read is to open the popups right away and change their behavior in the callback. Now this may work ofcourse with extra state that needs to retained till we enter the callback. Is there a better solution out there than this? Or should the saner minds stick to Synchronized XHR if its not causing too much trouble?

Comment: My opinion:  any design--visual or technical--that uses popups is doing it wrong.

Comment: *If* you know that there are already questions about this on SO, then it would be good to a.) *link to them* in your question and b.) tell us *why exactly* they are different from your question (and no: lack of acceptable answers is **not** a good reason to re-post the question).

Comment: @Joachim Just curious, why is lack of acceptable answers not a good reason to re-post the question? The question may have been asking the same thing but could have been posed badly resulting in poor responses. Can you not ask the same question but in a different way?

Comment: @MrMisterMan: if it's *really* the same question, then you should improve the original question. This way you *also* get it up on the main page and hopefully get some traffic in there. This way you *improve* the original question instead of duplicating it (which would waste quite some time, since people would post similar answers again).

Comment: [Synchronious XHR considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wer/archive/2011/08/03/why-you-should-use-xmlhttprequest-asynchronously.aspx)

Comment: @Joachim I surely couldn't find one question that summarizes my doubt completely. Now i did read few practices here n there, but considered it best to post the actual scenario, i m looking a solution for. Hope its not too bad to start this discussion.

Comment: @Joachim That sounds fair enough but how do you improve someone else's question? I'm assuming you mean by editing it but most people don't have editing privileges.

Comment: @MrMisterMan: yes, improving the question usually means editing it. Note that users with less than 2k reputation (even not-logged-in ones!) can still *suggest* edits to question and the link is even labeled "improve this question". If it's a real improvement, then it will quickly be accepted.

Comment: @Joachim Ah I see, I wasn't aware we could suggest edits. Thanks for the knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

> One clean solution that I've read is to open the popups right away and change their behavior in the callback.

That was going to be my answer when I saw the title of your question.

> Now this may work ofcourse with extra state that needs to retained till we enter the callback.

Declare the callback as a closure within the function that creates the pop-up.  It will inherit all the state and the browser won't lock up.

Comment: this mite have to handled differently, if i m opening more than 1 popup.

Comment: If you're opening more than 1 popup, then what @Stephen posted above is doubly true.

Comment: @Joachim Looks like this usecase should die its natural death & let the better sense prevail :) [ps] Although a down-vote was srsly uncalled for :-|